# SQL and Temporal data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Given a table of appointments, like this:

```
User     Start                    End
UserA    2016-01-15 12:00:00      2016-01-15 14:00:00    
UserA    2016-01-15 15:00:00      2016-01-15 17:00:00    
UserB    2016-01-15 13:00:00      2016-01-15 15:00:00    
UserB    2016-01-15 13:32:00      2016-01-15 15:00:00    
UserB    2016-01-15 15:30:00      2016-01-15 15:30:00    
UserB    2016-01-15 15:45:00      2016-01-15 16:00:00    
UserB    2016-01-15 17:30:00      2016-01-15 18:00:00
```

I want to create a list of distinct time intervals in which the same amount of people have an appointment:

```
Start                 End                   Count
2016-01-15 12:00:00   2016-01-15 13:00:00   1
2016-01-15 13:00:00   2016-01-15 14:00:00   2
2016-01-15 14:00:00   2016-01-15 15:45:00   1
2016-01-15 15:45:00   2016-01-15 16:00:00   2
2016-01-15 16:00:00   2016-01-15 17:00:00   1
2016-01-15 17:00:00   2016-01-15 17:30:00   0
2016-01-15 17:30:00   2016-01-15 18:00:00   1
```

How would I do this in SQL, preferably SQL Server 2008?

EDIT: To clarify: Manually, the result is obtained by making one row for each user, marking the blocked time, and then summing up the count of rows that have a mark:

```
Time  12  13  14  15  16  17
UserA xxxxxxxx    xxxxxxxx
UserB     xxxxxxxx   x      xx
Count 1   2   1      21   0 1
```

That result set would start at the minimum time available, end at the maximum time available, and while the ASCII art has only a 15min resolution, I would require at least resolution to the minute. I guess you can leave the rows with "0" out of the result, if this is easier for you.

Comment: Do you really need the `0` row? It can be tricky to conjure rows into existence based on zero source rows.

Comment: Where are you getting the Start and End times in your desired result set?  They don't match your data and they don't follow a pattern.

Comment: @devlincarnate - I think adjacent periods with the same number of users are consolidated, plus users seem to have appointments that overlap each other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's got to be an easier way than this, but at least you can probably follow each step individually:

```
declare @t table ([User] varchar(19) not null,Start datetime2 not null,[End] datetime2 not null)
insert into @t([User], Start, [End]) values
('UserA','2016-01-15T12:00:00','2016-01-15T14:00:00'),
('UserA','2016-01-15T15:00:00','2016-01-15T17:00:00'),
('UserB','2016-01-15T13:00:00','2016-01-15T15:00:00'),
('UserB','2016-01-15T13:32:00','2016-01-15T15:00:00'),
('UserB','2016-01-15T15:30:00','2016-01-15T15:30:00'),
('UserB','2016-01-15T15:45:00','2016-01-15T16:00:00'),
('UserB','2016-01-15T17:30:00','2016-01-15T18:00:00')

;With Times as (
    select Start as Point from @t
    union
    select [End] from @t
), Ordered as (
    select Point,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Point) as rn
    from Times
), Periods as (
    select
        o1.Point as Start,
        o2.Point as [End]
    from
        Ordered o1
            inner join
        Ordered o2
            on
                o1.rn = o2.rn - 1
), UserCounts as (
select p.Start,p.[End],COUNT(distinct [User]) as Cnt,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order BY p.[Start]) as rn
from
    Periods p
        left join
    @t t
        on
            p.Start < t.[End] and
            t.Start < p.[End]
group by
    p.Start,p.[End]
), Consolidated as (
    select uc.*
    from
        UserCounts uc
            left join
        UserCounts uc_anti
            on
                uc.rn = uc_anti.rn + 1 and
                uc.Cnt = uc_anti.Cnt
    where
        uc_anti.Cnt is null
    union all
    select c.Start,uc.[End],c.Cnt,uc.rn
    from
        Consolidated c
            inner join
        UserCounts uc
            on
                c.Cnt = uc.Cnt and
                c.[End] = uc.Start
)
select
    Start,MAX([End]) as [End],Cnt
from
    Consolidated
group by
    Start,Cnt
order by Start
```

[CTE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx)s are - `Times` - since any given start or end stamp can start or end a period in the final results, we just get them all in one column - so the `Ordered` can number them, and so that `Periods` can then re-assembly them into each smallest possible period.

`UserCounts` then goes back to the original data and finds out how many Users where overlapped by each calculated period.

`Consolidated` is the trickiest CTE to follow, but it's basically merging periods that abut each other where the user count is equal.

Results:

```
Start                       End                         Cnt
--------------------------- --------------------------- -----------
2016-01-15 12:00:00.0000000 2016-01-15 13:00:00.0000000 1
2016-01-15 13:00:00.0000000 2016-01-15 14:00:00.0000000 2
2016-01-15 14:00:00.0000000 2016-01-15 15:45:00.0000000 1
2016-01-15 15:45:00.0000000 2016-01-15 16:00:00.0000000 2
2016-01-15 16:00:00.0000000 2016-01-15 17:00:00.0000000 1
2016-01-15 17:00:00.0000000 2016-01-15 17:30:00.0000000 0
2016-01-15 17:30:00.0000000 2016-01-15 18:00:00.0000000 1
```

(And I even got the zero row I was unsure I'd be able to conjure into existence)

Answer (score 0):

This kind of query is much easier to write if you have a [calendar](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/) table.  But in this example I've built one on the fly using a [recursive CTE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx).  The CTE returns the appointment blocks, which we can then join to the appointment data.  I couldn't determine the interval pattern in your sample data, so I've shown the results in blocks of one hour.  You could modify this section, or define your own within a second table.

**Sample Data**

```
/* Table variables make sharing data easier    
 */
DECLARE @Sample TABLE
    (
        [User]      VARCHAR(50),
        [Start]     DATETIME,
        [End]       DATETIME
    )
;

INSERT INTO @Sample
    (
        [User],
        [Start],
        [End]
    )
VALUES
    ('UserA', '2016-01-15 12:00:00', '2016-01-15 14:00:00'),   
    ('UserA', '2016-01-15 15:00:00', '2016-01-15 17:00:00'),   
    ('UserB', '2016-01-15 13:00:00', '2016-01-15 15:00:00'),
    ('UserB', '2016-01-15 13:32:00', '2016-01-15 15:00:00'), 
    ('UserB', '2016-01-15 15:30:00', '2016-01-15 15:30:00'),
    ('UserB', '2016-01-15 15:45:00', '2016-01-15 16:00:00'),
    ('UserB', '2016-01-15 17:30:00', '2016-01-15 18:00:00')
;
```

I've used two variables to limit the returned results to just those appointments that fall within the given start and end point.

```
/* Set an start and end point for the next query    
 */
DECLARE @Start  DATETIME = '2016-01-15 12:00:00';
DECLARE @End    DATETIME = '2016-01-15 18:00:00';

WITH Calendar AS
    (
            /* Anchor returns start of first appointment    
             */
            SELECT
                @Start                                          AS [Start],
                DATEADD(SECOND, -1, DATEADD(HOUR, 1, @Start))   AS [End] 

        UNION ALL

            /* Recursion, keep adding new records until end of last appointment    
             */
            SELECT
                DATEADD(HOUR, 1, [Start])   AS [Start],
                DATEADD(HOUR, 1, [End])     AS [End]
            FROM
                Calendar
            WHERE
                [End] <= @End
    )
SELECT
    c    [Start],
    c    [End],
    COUNT(DISTINCT s    [User]) AS [Count]
FROM
    Calendar AS c
        LEFT OUTER JOIN @Sample AS s            ON s    [Start] BETWEEN c    [Start] AND c    [End]
                                                OR s    [End] BETWEEN c    [Start] AND c    [End]
GROUP BY
    c    [Start],
    c    [End]
;
```

Because an appointment can exceed one hour it may contribute to more than one row.  This explains why 7 sample rows leads to a returned total of 9.